# UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I have a class which i inject into a ViewModel + ViewModel factory, when initialise the view model in the onCreate method in activity, its says the value being passed through is not initialised.

Below is my code

I am quite new to Kotlin so have tried debugging but am stuck on this issue.

**Here is MainActivity code:**

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity(), RepoSelectedListener {


    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModel: MainActivityListViewModel

    lateinit var lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner
    lateinit var repoSelectedListener: RepoSelectedListener

    @Inject
    lateinit var repository: RepoRepository


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, ViewModelFactory(repository)).get(MainActivityListViewModel::class.java)

        repoRecyclerView.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            adapter = RepoListAdapter(viewModel, lifecycleOwner, repoSelectedListener)
        }


**My ViewModel:**



   class MainActivityListViewModel @Inject constructor(val 
    repoRepository: RepoRepository): BaseViewModel() {

    //private lateinit var repoRepository: RepoRepository
    private var disposable: CompositeDisposable? = null

    private val repos = MutableLiveData<List<Repo>>()
    private val repoLoadError = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    private val loading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()


     init {
        disposable = CompositeDisposable()
        fetchRepos()
      }

     fun getRepos(): LiveData<List<Repo>> {
        return repos
     }
    }
```

**my ViewModelFactory:**

```
   class ViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(private val 
   repoRepository: RepoRepository): ViewModelProvider.Factory{


    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if 
   (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(MainActivityListViewModel::class.java)) 
   {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return MainActivityListViewModel(this.repoRepository) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")

    }


   }
```

**my Class Repo:**

```
  class RepoRepository @Inject constructor(private val githubRepos: 
    GithubRepos){


    private lateinit var repoService: GithubRepos


    fun getRepositories(): Single<List<Repo>> {
        return repoService.getRepos()
    }

    fun getSingleRepo(owner: String, name: String): Single<Repo> {
        return repoService.getSingleRepo(owner, name)
    }
   }
```

**This is error i receive:**

```
   Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.carllewis14.repos/com.carllewis14.repos.ui.MainActivity}: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property 
  repository has not been initialized
```

Comment: you are accessing variable(repository) which must exist, but it is not initialized at a time, make it optional or initialize it before usage

Comment: You should inject your RepoRepository to your activity. Or inject MainActivityListViewModel and access your repo from viewmodel.

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik how do i initialize before usage is what i am asking

Comment: @EnsarBayhan the MainActivityListViewModel is injected already

Comment: @DanYon Yo have to inject to your MainActivity.

Comment: @EnsarBayhan i have updated the MainActivityListViewModel above to show the main is already injected into main activity

Comment: @DanYon Did you add injection to your activity? Like this "     AndroidInjection.inject(this)"

Comment: @EnsarBayhan That reference doesnt appear in my ide i get an unresolved reference for that class

Comment: @DanYon You can follow this guide https://medium.com/@iammert/new-android-injector-with-dagger-2-part-1-8baa60152abe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have a look at my answer here (maybe it helps ) [Nullable var with `?` vs. lateinit var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57133044/nullable-var-with-vs-lateinit-var/57133291#57133291)

Essentially, you are never initializing your `repository: RepoRepository`.

From the code you have written, you won't need an instance of your repository in your activity as well, it should just be created in the constructor of your `ViewModel` (which has injection)

You are also going to have a similar issue with `private lateinit var repoService: GithubRepos`; if it's in the constructor of your object, you don't have to declare it again.

Comment: just to clarify i wont need to inject `repository: RepoRepository`, in my activity because its injected into my viewmodel? so i should just have the viewmodel creation as `viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainActivityListViewModel::class.java)` ? As if i include my viewmodelfactory like :` viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, ViewModelFactory(repository)).get(MainActivityListViewModel::class.java)` then i have to add the instance as it appears in my viewmodel factory constructor

Comment: ok let me try that and get back to you @a_local_nobody i appreciate the help

Answer (score 57):

This is because you are trying to use the repository before initializing it with an instance without checking its initialization.

When using `lateinit` [nullity cannot be used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44796102/5279996) in that variable.

`lateinit var repository: RepoRepository`

Then, before using any method of the object, check that it is initialized:

`if (::repository.isInitialized) {}`

GL

Comment: lateinit  is not allowed on nullable types

Comment: Then the isInitialized is like a null check. Why not using a nullable property for these cases?

Answer (score 6):

if you're using Kotlin 1.2, you can easily check whether a lateinit variable has been initialized or not. If not, well, you can always use the not null approach.

Anyways, here's how you can check if a lateinit var has been initialized or not:

```
if (::fullName.isInitialized) {
    print("Hi, $fullName")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems the question code is shadowing the injection
FYI
you can also initialize by lazy :

> To create an object that will be initialized at the first access to it, we can use the lazy method:

```
val lazyValue: ClassWithHeavyInitialization by lazy {
        numberOfInitializations.incrementAndGet()
        ClassWithHeavyInitialization()
    }
```

https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin-lazy-initialization
also see kotlin docs

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your dagger version should be updated.

[image]

https://github.com/google/dagger/releases