# How to @Autowire a JPA repository in graphql-java-tools Resolver

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, graphql

I use Spring JPA and GraphQL-Java-Kickstart set of libs with Kotlin.
When I send a query to my app it throws this:

```
2020-02-26 18:51:42.707 ERROR 2672 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] g.k.e.error.DefaultGraphQLErrorHandler   : Error executing query Exception while fetching data (/createUser) : lateinit property userRepository has not been initialized

kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property userRepository has not been initialized
at com.minerepo.minerepo.resolver.mutation.RootMutationResolver.createUser(RootMutationResolver.kt:16) ~[main/:na]
```

This is my resolver:

```
@Component
class RootMutationResolver : GraphQLMutationResolver {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var userRepository: UserRepository

    fun createUser(user: UserInput): User = userRepository.save(User(
            id = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
            email = user.email,
            nick = user.nick
    ))
}
```

This is an entity:

```
@Entity
data class User(
        @Id val id: String,
        @NotNull @Email var email: String,
        @NotBlank @Length(min=4, max=64) var nick: String
) : ProjectOwner // Table-per-class inheritance
```

This is the input type class:

```
data class UserInput(
        var email: String,
        var nick: String
)
```

This is the repository:

```
@Repository
@Component
interface UserRepository : JpaRepository<User, String>
```

And this is the main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
class MinerepoApplication {
    @Bean
    fun schema() : GraphQLSchema = SchemaParser.newParser()
            .file("schema.graphqls")
            .resolvers(RootQueryResolver(), RootMutationResolver())
            .build()
            .makeExecutableSchema()
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<MinerepoApplication>(*args)
}
```

Comment: you may need to do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57182703/uninitializedpropertyaccessexception-lateinit-property-has-not-been-initialized

Comment: So it is better to use `UserRepository?` instead of `lateinit` and check for nullity when it is called?

Comment: from the link,yes

Comment: It didn't make much difference, now the query just returns null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you autowire `UserRepository` in anothor component (not GraphQL component)?

I think you miss the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation over the `MinerepoApplication` class. Example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = [MinerepoApplication::class])
class MinerepoApplication {
    @Bean
    fun schema() : GraphQLSchema = SchemaParser.newParser()
            .file("schema.graphqls")
            .resolvers(RootQueryResolver(), RootMutationResolver())
            .build()
            .makeExecutableSchema()
}
```

This will instruct Spring Data to scan the `MinerepoApplication` class package (and child packages) for JPA repositories.

You don't need the annotation `@Repository` and
`@Component` over the JPA repository interface. In addition, `@Repository` also works like `@Component`.

I would also like to add that when you inject the necessary dependencies in your components, you should not use `@Autowired` over the field, you should inject them through the constructor. Example:

```
@Component
class RootMutationResolver(
   private val userRepository: UserRepository
) : GraphQLMutationResolver {

    fun createUser(user: UserInput): User = userRepository.save(User(
            id = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
            email = user.email,
            nick = user.nick
    ))
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. I can wire the repository in my main class (I've checked only there), and it is not null even without `@EnableJpaRepositories`

Comment: I made it work this way:
1. I've used a constructor to inject the repository into the resolver
2. I've then injected the resolver into my application class and used the instance instead of creating it
I think it didn't work because I've passed my own instance previously which likely Spring couldn't see.
The second part with the constructors of your answer have helped :)