# Android kotlin lateinit property has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin

I am getting the variable isn't initialized . kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property no_cyclevalue has not been initialized. Unable get data from editText to Spinner.

Comment: Write something to `no_cyclevalue` before reading it

Comment: thanks, Yes, I have done that. I am unable to get the value from editText.I am getting Null.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Pease read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable needs to be initialized first before you can use it.

```
lateinit var sampleString: String

fun main() {
   // initialize the variable word wi
   sampleString = "This is a string"

  // now you can use it 
  Log.d("TAG", sampleString)
}
```

also in Kotlin 1.2 you can do this to check if lateinit variable has been initialized or not

```
if (::sampleString.isInitialized) {
   Log.d("TAG", sampleString)
}
```

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57182703/uninitializedpropertyaccessexception-lateinit-property-has-not-been-initialized)