# Kotlin lateInit has not been initialised error crashing application

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I have an Android Kotlin application fragment with three elements in the resource layout:

```xml
<EditText android:id="@+id/forename_input_account"/>
<EditText android:id="@+id/surname_input_account"/>
<Button android:id="@+id/saveButton"/>
```

On clicking save I require the contents of the two EditText fields to write to the project Firebase Realtime DB.

In the account fragment file, I have the following:

```java
class AccountFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var forename_input_account: EditText
    lateinit var surname_input_account: EditText
    lateinit var saveButton: Button

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

            forename_input_account = forename_input_account
            surname_input_account = surname_input_account
            saveButton = saveButton

            saveButton.setOnClickListener {
                saveAccount()
            }

    }

    private fun saveAccount(){
        val firstname = forename_input_account.text.toString().trim()
        val lastname = lastname_input_account.text.toString().trim()

        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("mySaveLocation")
        val saveId = ref.push().key

        val myRecord = save(saveId, firstname, lastname)

        ref.child(saveId.toString()).setValue(myRecord).addOnCompleteListener{

        }
    }

}
```

firstname and lastname are being declared in a separate file as follows:

```
class Hero(val id: String?, val firstname: String, val lastname: String)
```

When I run the application and navigate to the fragment the application crashes with the following error:

> kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property forename_input_account has not been initialized

Comment: have a look at this post of mine, maybe it's useful to you :D https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57133044/nullable-var-with-vs-lateinit-var/57133291#57133291

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`forename_input_account = forename_input_account` sets `forename_input_account` to itself. That has no practical effect, and since you are trying to access the `lateinit var` before you assign a value to it, you crash.

If you are trying to use [Kotlin synthetic properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html#importing-synthetic-properties), remove the three `lateinit var` properties and just use Kotlin synthetic properties, scoped to refer to the inflated `view`.

Otherwise, you need to use `findViewById()` or something to get the `View` to assign to those `lateinit var` properties (e.g., `forename_input_account = view.findViewById(R.id.forename_input_account)`).

Comment: "That has no effect." Normally, yes, but here it does: throwing an exception.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov: Thanks for the feedback! I have tried to clarify my point.

Answer (score 2):

You can add onCreateView and set layout inside it

```
fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, @Nullable container: ViewGroup, @Nullable savedInstanceState: Bundle): View {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.example, container, false)
}
```

Comment: OK. Where would you do this instead?  Thanks

Comment: I have added solution. Thanks